# Write reusable view

Tags: python, django, csv, model-view-controller

I have this function that takes a `QuerySet` and renders a CSV. I would like to write a view that renders a template with options to download different CSV files (Basically for anything defined in *models.py*)

```
# Exports CSV file using a QuerySet
def export(qs, fields=None, file_name='data'):
    model = qs.model
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}-{1}.csv'.format(file_name, str(datetime.date.today()))
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    # Write headers to CSV file
    if fields:
        headers = fields
    else:
        headers = []
        for field in model._meta.fields:
            headers.append(field.name)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    # Write data to CSV file
    for obj in qs:
        row = []
        for field in headers:
            if field in headers:
                val = getattr(obj, field)
                if callable(val):
                    val = val()
                row.append(val)
        writer.writerow(row)
    # Return CSV file to browser as download
    return response
```

Currently I am writing a NON-reusable view:

```
def csv_of_surveys(request):
    r = export(Survey.objects.all(), file_name='surveys')
    return r
```

What can I do? My only idea was to send a code over and write a switch statement, so

```
{% url "csv_of" 0 %}
{% url "csv_of" 1 %}
{% url "csv_of" 2 %}
{% url "csv_of" 3 %}
```

Where 0, 1, 2 and 3 would correspond to downloading different things.

The new view would look something like:

```
def csv_of(request, code):
    if code == 0:
        r = export(Survey.objects.all(), file_name='surveys')
        return r
    elif code == 1:
        r = export(User.objects.all(), file_name='teachers')
        return r
    elif code == 2:
        r = export(Student.objects.all(), file_name='students')
        return r
    # ...
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary that maps the given code to the associated object, then reduce all the if statements you have into one if. For the file name, it looks like you're doing the same thing each time, which is pluralizing and lowercasing it, in which case you should set it in model._meta.verbose_name_plural, then access that when you need it:

```
file_codes = {0:Survey,1:User...}
def csv_of(request, code):
  if int(code) in file_codes.keys():
    obj = file_codes[int(code)]
    return export(obj.objects.all(), file_name = obj._meta.verbose_name_plural.title())
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I assumed code was an int. Is that not the case? Note for posterity: My original code did not have the typecasting, which OP added, hence why I'm asking.

Comment: I have `url(r'^csv_of/(?P<code>\d+)$', csv_of, name='csv_of'),` in my `urls.py` which seems to be getting unicode, i.e. `u'2'` Shouldn't \d be interpreted as an integer? In other views, `classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=pk)` seems to work just fine using `url(r'^classroom_update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', classroom_update, name='classroom_update'),` in `urls.py`

Comment: I have verbose_name_plural set in model but it's returning `-django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x104f9c190`